# In flex mobile, how to open puffin web browser when clicked url within swf file?

Tags: ios, apache-flex, mobile

it's my first Question. plz read this.

now i'm developing Air mobile project.

it has many contents of flash(swf file) and it should be show that contents to user.

android is possible. but ios isn't.

i know puffin web browser.

but **i want user clicked swf file(url type), open puffin web browser and play clicked file.**

is it possible?

summary.

how launch puffin web browser or other app(able to load swf file) on my application?

and if it's possible, how pass url that clicked file?

thx read my question. have a good day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within a Flash Platform application you can use [navigateToURL()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29) to open a link.  Conceptually something like this:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.mydomain.com"));
```

In an AIR app;. this passes the request onto the underlying operating system.  From within your application you cannot control how the OS handles it; which means you cannot control which browser is launched.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, you can use `UIDocumentInteractionController` to call other apps: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html

For Puffin, Puffin registers `"puffin://"`, so as long as you set the URL as `"puffin://XXX"`, the system will bring up Puffin with URL = `"http://XXX"`. Also, "puffins://XXX" maps to `"https://XXX"`.